# How to remove message from Postfix queue depending on log output?

Tags: postfix

Server with Postfix forwards a lot of messages to Gmail. It is well configured, I can already catch 99% of spam but I would like to remove a message from the mail queue on first complaint by Google.

The complaint Google sends in /var/log/mail.log:

> Our system has detected that this message is 421-4.7.0 suspicious due
>   to the nature of the content and/or the links within. 421-4.7.0 To
>   best protect our users from spam, the message has been blocked.
>   421-4.7.0 Please visit 421 4.7.0 
>   https://support.google.com/mail/answer/188131 for more information.

I want to leave retry standard as it is for other than @gmail.com recipients. Any idea how to do this? I want to leave other e-mail in the queue because some of the recipients do not consider messages marked by Google as spam.